# When scroll table view content change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have custom table view cell that having rating stars. i'm using https://github.com/hsousa/HCSStarRatingView for rating View. 
there is my code for table view and cell view.

```
    class RatingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

      var value : CGFloat = 0.0
      @IBOutlet weak var starRatingView: HCSStarRatingView!
      @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
          initStarRatingView()
          starRatingView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DidChangeValue(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

      private func initStarRatingView() {
        var scalingTransform : CGAffineTransform!
        scalingTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1);
        starRatingView.transform = scalingTransform
        starRatingView.emptyStarImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "strokStar")
        starRatingView.halfStarImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "halfStar")
        starRatingView.filledStarImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fillStar")
        starRatingView.allowsHalfStars = true
      }


      @IBAction func DidChangeValue(_ sender: HCSStarRatingView) {

        self.value = sender.value
      }

class RatingViewController: CustomViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

  var values : [CGFloat] = [0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RatingTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RatingTableViewCell

    values[indexPath.row] = cell.value
    cell.starRatingView.value = values[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
//MARK: _Table data source

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    values.count
  }

}
```

there is a problem when i scroll table view. dequeue Reusable Cell data is wrong. how can update value data for each cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing the value in the cell. Take a look at those two lines:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RatingTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RatingTableViewCell
values[indexPath.row] = cell.value
```

You dequeue a cell and assign it's value to values[indexPath.row]. The problems that you are noticing when scrolling are caused by the fact that the reused cell was previously used for a different indexPath, which means that their value (that you assign to values[indexPath.row]) is meant for its previous indexPath.

To fix that, I would advise getting rid of the value variable in RatingTableViewCell. Instead, define a protocol RatingTableViewCellDelegate that will be used to inform the RatingViewController about the new value.

Comment: i defice protocol in tableCell class protocol RatingTableViewCellDelegate {
  
  func setCellRating(cell:RatingTableViewCell)
}

Comment: and call delegate method :  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
      initStarRatingView()
      starRatingView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DidChangeValue(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
     
      if let delegate = self.delegate {
        
        delegate.setCellRating(cell: self)
      }
    }

Comment: delegate condition not call

Comment: okk i got my problem. thanks for reply this solution work for me.